Should a sub-panel upstream from the main be bonded to ground?
If adding a 100 amp sub-panel from a meter box that is before the 200 amp main service panel. Do you need to bond neutral and ground wires together, like you would if installing the panel after the main?

What does before mean here? Is it feeding the main panel? Is it backfed from the main? Please revise to add more detail.

Depends what is in the subpanel. See 230.82...

The basic rule is that neutral and ground are bonded in exactly one place, and that place is your main service. So by definition the only things that can be "upstream" from the "main panel" are:

Meter - a meter by itself, not a "meter main"
Disconnect - provided it is only a disconnect and labeled as such

Which means that if you want to put a 100A subpanel upstream from a 200A "main panel" then one of the following has to be done (or already in place);

The meter is really a "meter main", the neutral-ground bond is in the meter main, and the 200A panel is a "main panel" in general function but not in terms of neutral-ground bond. This is actually quite common. When this is the case, one of the additional spaces in the meter main can be used to add a 100A breaker for the new subpanel and the existing "main" panel is already technically a subpanel too.
Replace the meter with a meter main.  Use the meter main to feed both the 200A main-now-subpanel and the 100A subpanel. Remove the neutral-ground bond in the old main panel and move any ground wires that are on the neutral bar in the old main panel to ground bars.
Add a new main panel, with neutral-ground bond, next to the meter. Use that to feed both the 200A main-now-subpanel and the 100A subpanel. Remove the neutral-ground bond in the old main panel and move any ground wires that are on the neutral bar in the old main panel to ground bars.
Feed the 100A subpanel from a breaker in the main panel. This may seem "backwards" as you have to run wires back towards the meter. However, it is the simplest option. In addition, the main panel should be pretty close to the meter for safety reasons (the wire between meter and main panel is supposed to be as short as possible because it is not protected from an overload).

In all cases, an NEC Load Calculation is needed. Presumably you are adding some large loads (EV charging, perhaps?) and need to make sure your utility service can handle the load. If it can't, then there are ways to deal with it. And, particularly with EV charging, you may be able to get away with less than you think - 30A or even 20A is enough for most people, most of the time.

The neutral and ground should only be bonded together at the main service panel. In the sub-panel, the neutral and ground should be kept separate. It is for preventing any potential ground loops and ensuring proper grounding and safety.
